# How do I process a 500,000 record pipe delimited file?

Tags: .net, windows

We receive files in pipe delimited text files and am looking for an efficient way to parse through the file looking for conformance errors. There is a template which specifies the rules i.e. length of a field, the data type of the field, whether its mandatory or not. So I'll be checking the pipe delimited file against that template (which is currently just a word document).

1. How do I parse the file without the PC freezing on me? (read it in chunks. Streamreader?)
2. Importantly, Where would you advice I store the "rules template"? in and XML file or in an sqlite database which has other application settings?

Any suggestions on how to best do this?

The tool has got to be in a windows environment (VB.Net)

Sample data:

```
Company A|Company A ltd|3453457675|C565474567||UK|C3423454534|b3345|A|003||D3KCI3KF||0|001||+44-22523280||P.O.BOX 42027|P.O.BOX 42027|LIVERPOOL|UK|00100|L.R. NO. 209/5827, BY PASS ROAD|OFF BY PASS ROAD||UK|UK|PEOPLE SOFT|PEOPLE SOFT|PEOPLESOFT|2345435|S||B|34344444|45556666|Z|0|BP|0|3445345|0|2343545654|0|0|D|23434534534||0||453564645||1232434523|0|324345230000101|0|S
```

Thanks.

Comment: Q: What do you mean by "pipe delimited"?  The "|" character?  Q: Can you provide some sample data?  Q: What does this "template" look like?  Q: What programming and/or scripting language are you using to read and validate the files?

Comment: The delimiter character shouldn't have much bearing on the solution. There are 1000 ways of writing a program to deal with this.

Comment: Q: "Am hoping the question is not subjective"  A: No, just hopelessly vague and unclear ;)  Please try to provide some more specifics ;)

Comment: pipe delimited = "|". Programming language vb.net. And the pipe really isn't the problem. See below. Template is just a word document rules on lenghts and formats of the data in the template. @mark-ransom, true, but I've just seen on done here and a 500,000 entry file takes 20 minutes to parse and validate with the biggest culprit being the whole file is being loaded into memory. I want to avoid that. The other challange is the rules template. Do I create an XML file to store this information or do I put the rules in sqlite? Suggestions welcome

Comment: Your question is a bit over broad, If you want to know how to parse a file without loading the whole file in to memory ask that (any only that). This question will get closed as overly broad as-is.

Comment: If there are no escaping or quoting rules, a simple `File.ReadLines(...).Select(line=>line.Split('|')` should do the job. If there are complications, look into a full csv parser.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks. seen `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader` but will do some more googling. What about the "rules engine"? where would you store that as it needs to be shipped with the application...

Comment: You need to break this down or it is going to get closed.   If a record is 40 bytes that is 2 GB.  If you have the memory reading it into memory is going to be the fastest.  You could read bytes from the files directly to keep the memory down but it is going to be slower and a lot harder to code.

Comment: How static are the rules? If they do not tend to change between releases of the application (assuming there is more than one) you can ship it as an embedded resource.

Answer (score -1):

SED - is a great tool - there are windows ports for it. rather PERL like options, but VERY fast and powerfull
I had to process hugh exchange logs and SED was able to process in seconds.